# How to force the browser to open a downloaded .msi file?

Tags: file

I need to force the browser to open the file instead of downloading it. For now all i found is php code to force download and force the opening, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=1.msi");
header("Content-type: application/msi");
readfile("1.msi");
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the content-type be "application/x-msi", "application/x-windows-installer"? Strictly it should be "application/octet-stream". And you may need to manually configure the web server to allow it to serve to first two types.

Comment: hadn't solved it...well i wonder if such thing even possible.Most ppl asking about force opening pdf...Thx for answer btw.I'll try to follow your advices

Answer (score 0):

I don't really uderstand what you mean, but you should replace every "1.msi" part of the script with an asterisk instead of the .msi, The asterisk is the jolly character, so the script will open any file with te .msi extension.

Comment: Thx.Well i want to send a link to a person smth like www.example.com/1.php .After clicking this link it must open the file automatically.Without the option of saving this file somewhere.

Comment: Where to save the file or executing it - is not handled by the website you download it from, but by a setting in your browser.

Comment: I am unsure.Ppl manage to write a script which opens pdf automatically...In browser...

Comment: The possibilities are two: 1. The script just open a page of the website which contains the PDF file, 2. The script opens the directory of the just-downloaded PDF file. This is possible becaus ethe browser can show PDF files, but not the .msi ones.